# iptables time rule doen't work on ubuntu 20.04

Tags: ubuntu, iptables

This is my rule:

```
iptables -A INPUT -m mac --mac-source 40:e2:30:f4:00:04 -m time --timestart 18:00:00 --timestop 23:59:59 --weekdays Mon,Tue,Wed,Thu,Fri -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -m mac --mac-source 40:e2:30:f4:00:04 -j DROP
```

it doesn't work in 20.04 (iptables v1.8.4). any help?

PD: [Here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1212886/828892) author says that this is because iptables does not read the system time but UTC. I tried the rule and it doesn't work either

```
iptables -A INPUT -m mac --mac-source 40:e2:30:f4:00:04 --match time --weekdays Mon,Tue,Wed,Thu,Fri --timestart $(date -u -d @$(date "+%s" -d "18:00") +%H:%M) --timestop $(date -u -d @$(date "+%s" -d "23:00") +%H:%M) -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -m mac --mac-source 40:e2:30:f4:00:04 -j DROP
```

PD: I have used the `--kerneltz` ([HERE](https://serverfault.com/a/508299/480349) explanation) parameter which supposedly uses the kernel timezone, instead of UTC, but neither (and using [--kerneltz is highly discouraged](https://ipset.netfilter.org/iptables-extensions.man.html#:%7E:text=using%20--kerneltz%20is%20highly%20discouraged))

my pc hour:

```
timedatectl status
               Local time: sáb 2021-08-28 12:42:49 -05
           Universal time: sáb 2021-08-28 17:42:49 UTC
                 RTC time: sáb 2021-08-28 17:42:48    
                Time zone: America/Bogota (-05, -0500)
System clock synchronized: yes                        
              NTP service: active                     
          RTC in local TZ: no

date --utc 
sáb 28 ago 2021 17:44:23 UTC
```

I would appreciate if the solution was not to set the UTC time on my computer, because this can affect other applications

another rule doesn't work (maclist.txt content 40:e2:30:f4:00:04 and others)

```
current_time=$(date +%H) # actual 13
allowed_time=08
denied_time=12
maclist=$(awk '{print $1}' maclist.txt)
if [ \( $current_time -ge $allowed_time -a $current_time -lt $denied_time \) ]; then
    for mac in $(echo -e "$maclist"); do
        iptables -I INPUT -m mac --mac-source $mac -j NFLOG --nflog-prefix 'macblock'
        iptables -I INPUT -m mac --mac-source $mac -j ACCEPT
        iptables -I FORWARD -m mac --mac-source $mac -j NFLOG --nflog-prefix 'macblock'
        iptables -I FORWARD -m mac --mac-source $mac -j ACCEPT
    done
fi
```

out `sudo iptables -nvL`

```
    0     0 NFLOG      tcp  --  eno2   *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            MAC 40:e2:30:f4:00:04 TIME from 08:00:00 to 17:59:59 UTC nflog-prefix  blockports
    0     0 DROP       tcp  --  eno2   *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            MAC 40:e2:30:f4:00:04 TIME from 08:00:00 to 17:59:59 UTC
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  eno2   *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            MAC 40:e2:30:f4:00:04
```

Comment: What tests did you use to confirm the rule does not work? Criteria should be system on current LAN with specified MAC, and testing during the interval 18:00:80 to 23:59:59 UTC on one of the named weekdays

Comment: Notice that your UTC conversion period is an hour shorter than your first example (`23:00` vs `23:59:59`)

Comment: The test I did was to run the rule and allow the mac address no matter what time I put in the rule

Comment: Add a rule in front of those, `iptables -I INPUT -m mac --mac-source 40:e2:30:f4:00:04 -j LOG`. Do you get messages in your kernel logfile? (You may get one per packet, so take care!) If not, your MAC criterion is wrong

Comment: there is nothing in the log. It doesn't matter what I do or how I do it. This mac will continue to have access at any time. Please test the posted rules and check for yourself. Hopefully I'm wrong, but from all the tests I've done these time rules seem to no longer work on ubuntu 20.04

Comment: @ajcg from your own comment it looks like the time match is not the cause of your problems: you are looking at the wrong cause.

Comment: Can you define "Works in ubuntu 14:04 (i don't know in 16.04) but not in 18.04/20.04 (iptables v1.8.4). any help?" does it mean that in 18.04/20.04 there is always traffic or that there is never traffic? Or put an other way: what is the result of `iptables-save -c | grep -w mac`? Especially the counters in front of the rules are of interest.

Comment: I am going to withdraw that statement because I no longer have the way to prove it

Comment: You still shoud address roaima's last comment or my own previous comment (iptables-save -c ...), or that would mean the whole question is about the wrong problem.

Comment: the problem, i think is hour UTC vs local time

Comment: You might think this, but no the problem is the mac address match.

Comment: Not helping: a new MAC appeared in the question: 08:00:27:7D:82:DB

Comment: I appreciate your help, but I still have the problem. I have tried several scenarios and the results are the same. I have tried with different macs and the same thing always happens. If you want me to post additional information just ask and I will post it. But I can't continue on this thread. If someone has an answer I would appreciate it if it is published and if it solves the problem I will mark it as correct. Thanks.

Comment: You already did: the mac only rules have zero match. As long as they show zero match, the question isn't about a problem with the time match. Can't help further until you accept this.

Comment: If you are getting no match to the `iptables LOG` setting then your sending system isn't using the MAC you defined in the rule. You need to fix that before proceeding. Or remove the MAC criterion from the ruleset. Are you guessing the MAC? On your server, use `arp -na` to find the real MAC for the expected IP address

Comment: Your script is putting the rules into the table in reverse. Your first rule in each table is therefore `ACCEPT`. Use `iptables -A` to append in order. Once you've fixed that change the `NFLOG` to `LOG` so that you can actually see the log messages that should be produced